# Regular expression in struts

Tags: java, regex, struts

I am validating the decimal places with precision (5,2) which can have negative numbers using regular expresion in struts.
When I try to run this     `^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})$`
in java it is working fine. But, the same expression in struts is throwing below error.

`org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks processFailure mask validation failed for property inputCost: org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: ^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})$
Nested repetitions *?+ in expression`

Here is the code snippet of validation.xml.

```
        <field property="inputCost" depends="double,mask">
            <arg position="0"  key="label.inputCost"/>
            <msg name="mask" key="label.inputCost.mask"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>mask</var-name>
                <var-value>^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})$</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>
```

Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is technically incorrect. You can't have a `+` after a `{,}` qualifier, it's like saying `.*+` or `.?*` (the `+` is a special metacharacter in regex meaning "one or more", just like `*` means "zero or more").

Try

```
^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})$
```

Notice the `{1,3}+` is just a `{1,3}`.

Comment: A `+` after a quantifier makes the quantifier a "possessive quantifier" that means it does not backtrack. But not all flavours supports possessive quantifiers. See e.g. here in the [Perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Possessive-quantifiers)

Comment: Ahh, thanks @stema. I've never come across that particular quirk before, I think the more common one to achieve that is the `(?>...)` construct (a bit more widely supported, although still not common).